# Why doesn't a missing parameter in printf produce an error

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

In the following code -

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int a=10,b=20,c=30;
    printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,c);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

the output contains 10,20 and 30 in their respective positions, but the remaining %d format specifiers output garbage values. Why doesn't it give an error if we don't specify the required number of parameters? Is this useful sometimes?

Code link: [ideone](http://ideone.com/DNnzrA)

Comment: "undefined behavior" means **undefined** behavior. It isn't called "guaranteed crash behavior" or "runtime error behavior" *for a reason.*

Comment: Some compilers are smart enough to compare the format specifiers with the arguments supplied, but not all.

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate, but it's not a *bad* question. It's well-posed with an sscce. Shouldn't be downvoted - vote to close as a duplicate instead.

Comment: @Bathsheba But part of the message on downvoting is "This question does not show any research effort", which is exactly what this question demonstrates.

Comment: @Jashaszun: That's a fair point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [*undefined*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you pass fewer arguments than the format specifiers. Compiler is not required to produce any errors on undefined behaviour.

Although, most compilers would do. GCC, for example, produces the following for your code:

```
warning: too few arguments for format
```

when compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 file.c
```